# Ques Classification Using Support Vector Machines

Tags: pyspark, svm, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to classify Questions using SVM. I am following this link for reference -

https://shirishkadam.com/2017/07/03/nlp-question-classification-using-support-vector-machines-spacyscikit-learnpandas/

But they have used SPACY,SCIKIT-LEARN and PANDAS. I want to do the same thing using Spark Mllib.
I am using this code to create a Dataframe -

```
sc = SparkContext(conf=sconf)  # SparkContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
data = sc.textFile("<path_to_csv_file>")
header = data.first()
trainingDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data
    .filter(lambda line: line != header)
    .map(lambda line: line.split("|"))
    .map(lambda line: ([line[0]], [line[2]], [line[6]]))).toDF("Question", "WH-Bigram", "Class")
```

And I am getting following result by printing the dataframe- `trainingDF.show(3)`

```
+--------------------+-------------------+------+
|            Question|          WH-Bigram| Class|
+--------------------+-------------------+------+
|[How did serfdom ...|          [How did]|[DESC]|
|[What films featu...|       [What films]|[ENTY]|
|[How can I find a...|          [How can]|[DESC]|
```

My sample csv file is -

```
#Question|WH|WH-Bigram|Class
How did serfdom develop in and then leave Russia ?|How|How did|DESC
```

I am using word2vec to create training data for SVM and trying to train using SVM.

```
word2Vec1 = Word2Vec(vectorSize=2, minCount=0, inputCol="Question", outputCol="result1")
training = word2Vec1.fit(trainingDF).transform(trainingDF)
model = SVMWithSGD.train(training, iterations=100)
```

After using word2vec my data is converted in this format -

```
[Row(Question=[u'How did serfdom develop in and then leave Russia ?'], WH-Bigram=[u'How did'], Class=[u'DESC'], result1=DenseVector([0.0237, -0.186])), Row(Question=[u'What films featured the character Popeye Doyle ?'], WH-Bigram=[u'What films'], Class=[u'ENTY'], result1=DenseVector([-0.2429, 0.0935]))]
```

But when I try to train the dataframe using SVM then getting error that `TypeError: data should be an RDD of LabeledPoint, but got <class 'pyspark.sql.types.Row'>`

I am stuck here...i think the dataframe that i have created is not correct.
Do any body know how to create a suitable dataframe for training it with SVM. And Please let me know if I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Great that you are trying out one of the machine learning methods in Spark, but there are multiple problems with your approach,

1) Your data has multiple classes, it is not a binary classification model hence SVM in Spark won't work on this dataset (you can have a look at the source code [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.2.0/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/classification/SVM.scala)). You can try the one class vs all others approach and train as many models as there are classes in your data. However, you would be better off using something like the MultilayerPerceptronClassifier or the multiclass logistic model in Spark.

2) Secondly,  Mllib is very unforgiving in terms of the class labels that you use, you can only specify 0,1,2 or 0.0,1.0,2.0 etc i.e it does not automatically infer the number of classes based on your output column. Even if you specify two classes as 1.0 & 2.0 it will not work it has to be 0.0 & 1.0.

3) You need to use a labeledpoint RDD instead of a spark dataframe, remember that spark.mllib is for use with RDD's whereas spark.ml is for use with dataframes. On help for how to create a Labeledpoint rdd you may refer to the spark documentation [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html) where there are multiple examples.

4) On a feature engineering note, I don't think you would want to take the vectorSize as 2 for your word2vec model (something like 10 would be more appropriate as a starting point), these are simply too less for giving a reasonable prediction.